# El uso de "sí + que" al contestar a alguien

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras

Yo sé en general cómo usar "sí" en las oraciones con en significado "what I DO have though...", como en un ejemplo abajo:

"*El dinero no lo tengo. Pero lo que **sí** tengo...*"

No obstante, encontré el uso de esta estructura con "que".

De "La Víctima Número Ocho" (España):

*-Yo no ronco, tía.*

*-Sí, **sí que** roncas.*

Un ejemplo más de "La Víctima Número Ocho":

*-Tú no has matado a nadie.*

*-**Sí que** le he matado, Omar.*

Un ejemplo más de "La Víctima Número Ocho":

*No sé por qué lo hizo, pero **sí que** tengo clara una cosa, que ni usted ni sus hombres tienen intención de detener a Omar Jamal.*

De "Tesis" (España, el año 1996):

*-Pero es un cabronazo!*

*-¡Tú **sí que** lo eres!*

Preguntas:

1. ¿Cómo usar esta estructura? ¿En cuáles circunstancias?
2. ¿Sería gramaticalmente incorrecto no usar "que" en estos ejemplos? ¿O "que" es imprescindible aquí?

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores si hay algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tanto "sí" como "sí que" tienen valor enfático. El adverbio "sí" solo puede usarse en (1), y tanto "sí" como la construcción "sí que" pueden usarse en (2):

1. Oraciones copulativas enfáticas de relativo:

- Dinero no tengo, pero lo que **sí** tengo es salud.
- José no sabe nada, pero quien **sí** sabe es Juan.

2. Delante de cualquier frase verbal fuera de una oración enfática (si bien ambas formas son correctas, "sí que" fluye con más facilidad):

- A. Yo no ronco.
  B. **Sí** roncas / **Sí que** roncas.
- A. Tú no has matado a nadie. B. **Sí** he matado a alguien / **Sí que** he matado a alguien.
- A. No soy ningún cabrón. B **Sí** lo eres / **Sí que** lo eres.